# Possible bug in version 12 in solving the eigensystem

Tags: eigenvalues, version-12

I would like to report a possible bug in solving the eigensystem, at least for certain matrix. I use version 12 in mac. I will attach the minimal working example below. Excuse me for the improper format as this is my first time to post here. I will attach a screenshot for the result at the very end. You may notice that I have restarted the kernel, but the problem is still there. Thank you in advance for the help.

Here we go the code.

```
H={{0,0,Exp[I k1]+m1,Exp[I k2]+m2},{0,0,Exp[I Phi](Exp[-I k2]+m2),Exp[-I k1]+m1},{Exp[-I k1]+m1,Exp[-I Phi](m2+Exp[I k2]),0,0},{Exp[-I k2]+m2,Exp[I k1]+m1,0,0}};

H // MatrixForm
{eigval, eigvec} = Eigensystem[H];
vvv = {eigvec[[1]], eigvec[[3]]};
diffvvv = vvv[[1]] - vvv[[2]];
diffvvv /. Phi -> Pi
```

[image]

Comment: Per policy, please do not use the `Bugs` tag until the community has verified the behavior is indeed caused by a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and removing the inappropriate tag.

Comment: The corresponding eigenvalues are equal for that substitution. `In[550]:= Together[eigval[[1]] - eigval[[3]]] /. Phi -> Pi

Out[550]= 0` (Posswibly more convincing: `In[552]:= Limit[Together[eigval[[1]] - eigval[[3]]], Phi -> Pi]

Out[552]= 0`)

Answer (score 10):

I think you hit an Indeterminate form.

```
H = {{0, 0, Exp[I k1] + m1, Exp[I k2] + m2}, {0, 0, 
    Exp[I Phi] (Exp[-I k2] + m2), Exp[-I k1] + m1}, {Exp[-I k1] + m1, 
    Exp[-I Phi] (m2 + Exp[I k2]), 0, 0}, {Exp[-I k2] + m2, 
    Exp[I k1] + m1, 0, 0}};
{eigval, eigvec} = Eigensystem[H];
vvv = {eigvec[[1]], eigvec[[3]]};
```

Now see what happens here

```
(vvv /. Phi -> Pi) // Simplify
```

> {{0, 0, Indeterminate, 1}, {0, 0, Indeterminate, 1}}

You can see that also if you replace your code with Limit, you get different result

```
diffvvv = vvv[[1]] - vvv[[2]];
diffvvv /. Phi -> Pi
(* {0,0,0,0} *)
```

With

```
diffvvv = vvv[[1]] - vvv[[2]];
Limit[diffvvv, Phi -> Pi]
(* {Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, 0} *)
```

You can also see the result is different if you replace `Phi` with `Pi` in the matrix itself before finding eigenvectors

```
H = {{0, 0, Exp[I k1] + m1, Exp[I k2] + m2}, {0, 0, 
    Exp[I Phi] (Exp[-I k2] + m2), Exp[-I k1] + m1}, {Exp[-I k1] + m1, 
    Exp[-I Phi] (m2 + Exp[I k2]), 0, 0}, {Exp[-I k2] + m2, 
    Exp[I k1] + m1, 0, 0}};
H = H /. Phi -> Pi;
{eigval, eigvec} = Eigensystem[H];
vvv = {eigvec[[1]], eigvec[[3]]};
diffvvv = (vvv[[1]] - vvv[[2]]) // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It should not have made difference if one replaces `Phi` with `Pi` before or after.

So it is safer to use `Limit` instead of direct substitution to avoid this problem.